# i need to compare timestamps of given array elements and push those elements to new arrays based on that comparison in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, time, timestamp

i have an array containing a timestamp for each object
i need to check timestamp of each object and push the whole object to a corresponding array .
i'v tried the following and its working but the problem is i have a huge data and the process takes a lot of time to finish :

```js
      const thisMonthArray = []
      const thisYearArray = []
      const thisQuarterArray = []

      data = [
        {id:'1',createdOn:1631166889,items:[{itemname:'name1',details:'details1'}]},
        {id:'2',createdOn:1625291689,items:[{itemname:'name2',details:'details2'}]},
        {id:'3',createdOn:1612335289,items:[{itemname:'name3',details:'details3'}]}
      ]


      const fillTheArrays = (element) => {
        // element timestamp
        const timestamp = element.createdOn
        const milliseconds = timestamp * 1000
        const dateObject = new Date(milliseconds)
        let createTime = dateObject.toLocaleString()
        createTime = createTime.substr(0, createTime.indexOf(','))
        const createyear = createTime.substr(createTime.lastIndexOf('/') + 1)
        const createmonth = createTime.substr(0, createTime.indexOf('/'))

        // current timestamp
        const currenstamp = Date.now()
        const currentDateObj = new Date(currenstamp)
        let currentDate = currentDateObj.toLocaleString()
        currentDate = currentDate.substr(0, currentDate.indexOf(','))
        const currentyear = currentDate.substr(currentDate.lastIndexOf('/') + 1)
        const currentmonth = currentDate.substr(0, currentDate.indexOf('/'))

        if (createyear === currentyear) {
          if (createmonth === currentmonth) {
            thisMonthArray.push(element)
          } else if (createmonth >= (currentmonth - 3)) {
            thisQuarterArray.push(element)
          } else {
            thisYearArray.push(element)
          }
        }
      }
    
      data.forEach(element => fillTheArrays (element))
        let results = { cratedOn: Date.now(), thisMonth: thisMonthArray, thisQuarter: thisQuarterArray, thisYear: thisYearArray }

        console.log(results)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use an `intervals` object to define what intervals we are interested in, adding a `start` and `end` property to each.

Once we have this defined, we can create our `fillTheArrays` function that will loop over each interval and use `Array.reduce()` and `Array.filter()` to get data items for each interval. A date item is considered to be part of the interval if the createdOn property is greater than or equal to the interval start and less than or equal to the interval end.

By avoiding calls to new Date() and String.substr() etc, we will substantially improve performance using this approach.

```js
const year = new Date().getFullYear();
const month = new Date().getMonth();
const quarter = Math.ceil((month + 1) / 3);

const data = [
    {id:'1',createdOn:1631166889,items:[{itemname:'name1',details:'details1'}]},
    {id:'2',createdOn:1625291689,items:[{itemname:'name2',details:'details2'}]},
    {id:'3',createdOn:1612335289,items:[{itemname:'name3',details:'details3'}]}
];
      
const intervals = {
    thisYear: { start: new Date(year, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0).getTime(), end: new Date(year, (quarter - 1) * 3, 0, 23, 59, 59).getTime() },
    thisQuarter: { start: new Date(year, (quarter - 1) * 3, 1, 0, 0, 0).getTime(), end: new Date(year, quarter * 3, 0, 23, 59, 59).getTime() },
    thisMonth: { start: new Date(year, month, 1, 0, 0, 0).getTime(), end: new Date(year, month + 1, 0, 23, 59, 59).getTime() }
}

console.log(`Interval\tStart\t\t\tEnd`);
Object.entries(intervals).forEach(([key,value]) => { 
    console.log(`${key}\t${new Date(value.start).toLocaleString('sv')}\t${new Date(value.end).toLocaleString('sv')}`);
})

function fillTheArrays(intervals, data) {
     // Start by filtering by the minimum start and maximum end date of our intervals.
    const minStart = Math.min(...Object.values(intervals).map(({start}) => start));
    const maxEnd = Math.max(...Object.values(intervals).map(({end}) => end));
    const inRangeData = data.filter(entry => (entry.createdOn * 1000 >= minStart) && (entry.createdOn * 1000 <= maxEnd));
    
    return Object.entries(intervals).reduce((acc, [key, value]) => {
        acc[key] = inRangeData.filter(entry => {
            return (entry.createdOn * 1000 >= value.start) 
                && (entry.createdOn * 1000 <= value.end)
        });
        return acc;
    }, { createdOn: Date.now() })
}

console.log('\nResult:', JSON.stringify(fillTheArrays(intervals, data), null, 2))
```

Comment: hello terry , thank you for your answer 
but its taking more time to complete the task this way , { thisYear } Object must include data from this year && not from this quarter or current month. 

what to do in order to fix that using your answer

Comment: I've added some optimizations to ensure the code will run a little faster. After checking that a date is in this year, we'll reduce the values we search for this quarter to those of this year and so on with this month. This will reduce the time taken significantly. Also, we'll use .getTime() for each interval value to further reduce the number of operations.

Comment: I've also edited to ensure thisYear does not contain data from this quarter or this month.

Comment: Glad to be of help!

Answer (score 0):

Odeh, how are you doing?

Based on what you showed, I believe you can simplify some of the code. Have you tried using the Date object instance functions instead of hard-coding some behavior, such as:

```js
// instead of getting the year by cutting the createTime string variable, you could simply compare both date objects:

dateObject.getFullYear() === currentDateObject.getFullYear()
```

You can read more [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date#instance_methods)

Comment: hi , thanks a lot.
it was very helpful , but nothing happened with the response time . 
:(